# Plotting points on UIImage on different devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

I'm trying to draw a rectangle in a view, and that view sits over a UIImage. The problem I'm encountering is that if I set the rect coords to draw a rect on a persons face in the image for an iphone 5 screen, that rectangle is not located on the persons face for an Ipad2 screen. I have taken into account the screen differences and have applied the equation newCoord = oldCoord * scaleFactor, but the rectangle is still off.  Here is my sample code that draws the rectangle:

```
(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    //image size

    int origWidth = 847;
    int origHeight = 466;

    int x = 433;
    int y = 173;


    CGFloat newWidth = self.frame.size.width;

    CGFloat newHeight = self.frame.size.height;

    CGFloat wScaleFactor = newWidth / origWidth;

    CGFloat hScaleFactor = newHeight / origHeight;


    int newX = x * wScaleFactor;

    int newY = y * hScaleFactor;

    // Get the contextRef

    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // Set the circle fill color to GREEN

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 0.0, 255.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(newX,newY,5,5);

    // Draw the rectangle border

    CGContextFillRect(contextRef, rectangle); 
}
```

Any help on what I'm missing is appreciated.

I should also mention that my UIimage is set to aspectFit.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a image that show what you are getting and maybe one to show what you are expecting?

Comment: Hey did you get any solutions to your problem ? Any help will be much appreciated !